# copying uint8 into a matrix using fscanf() in C

Tags: c, file, scanf

I want to copy a file in a matrix but it doesn't work. I think that there is a problem in my way to get hexidecimal number into file, maybe i don't use a correct specifier. For the algoritm, i think that it's correct but i don't understand why the first line become a first column in the result. 
This is the result that i have :

```
63 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7c 0 ...
77 0 ...
7b 0 ...
f2 0 ...
6b 0 ...
6f 0 
c5 0 
30 0 
1 0  
67 0 
2b 0 
fe 0 
d7 0 ...
ab 0 ...
76 0 ...
```

The first column corresponding to the first line into the file.
Thanks for your help
look at my programs

```
typedef uint8_t Sbox [16][16];

const int SBOX_ROWS = 16;
const int SBOX_COLS = 16;

Sbox* read_sbox(FILE *fp)
{

    Sbox* result = NULL;
    int i,j;
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        result = (Sbox*)malloc(sizeof(Sbox));
        for (i = 0 ; i < SBOX_ROWS ; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0 ; j < SBOX_COLS-1 ; j++)
            {
                fscanf(fp,"%x",result[i][j]);
            }
            fscanf(fp,"%x\n",result[i][SBOX_COLS-1]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    Sbox* res = NULL;
    int i,j;
    if ((fp = fopen("sbox.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file: sbox.txt\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Dans else\n");
        res = read_sbox(fp);
    }
    if (res == NULL)
    {
        printf("res NULL\n");       
    }
    for (i = 0 ; i < SBOX_ROWS ; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0 ; j < SBOX_COLS-1 ; j++)
            {
                printf("%x ",(*res)[i][j]);
            }
           printf("%x\n",(*res)[i][j]);
        } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `result = (Sbox*)malloc(sizeof(Sbox) * SBOX_ROWS * SBOX_COLS);` Why not being `result = (Sbox*)malloc(sizeof(Sbox));` simply ???

Comment: fscanf gets a pointer to the memory it reads into like this: fscanf(fp,"%x",&result[i][j]);       
fscanf(fp,"%x\n",&result[i][SBOX_COLS-1]);

Comment: Usually, we do one malloc for the lines and one malloc for each line. Also, I don't think you need to deal with `fscanf(fp,"%x\n"` separately.

Comment: @Desolator I modified but it doesn't work

Comment: @dragosht : I think that it's same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem is that you are reading an integer with fscanf() into a byte (uint8) which is not large enough to hold it.

Instead do:

```
fscanf(fp,"%x",&u);
(*result)[i][j] = (uint8_t)u;
```

where `u` is an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Thank you for posting the correct code, I edited mine. @JonathanIlambo

Answer (score 1):

```
Sbox* read_sbox(FILE *fp)
{
    unsigned int u;
    Sbox* result = NULL;
    int i,j;
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        result = (Sbox*)malloc(sizeof(Sbox));
        for (i = 0 ; i < SBOX_ROWS ; ++i)
        {
            for (j = 0 ; j < SBOX_COLS-1 ; ++j)
            {
                fscanf(fp,"%x",&u);
            (*result)[i][j] = (uint8_t)u; 
            }
            fscanf(fp,"%x\n",&u);
            (*result)[i][SBOX_COLS-1] = (uint8_t) u;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```